# How to make a select with grouping in MongoDB

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo and I try to obtain a group given by the identity document, the equivalent in sql would have the following form:

```
SELECT fecIni, idc , cic 
from db.cllAuditoria 
WHERE fecIni BETWEEN '2017-07-01T05:00:00.000Z' AND '2017-07-31T05:00:00.000Z' 
group by idc , cic
```

please friends, this would help me a lot I have researched from different sources without coming up with the solution, I thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post a sample document and expected output? also there is no aggregation on column `fecIni` in your SQL

Answer (score 1):

Assuming U have collection like:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a58dafe1aadbcd8ae74572e"),
    "fecIni" : ISODate("2017-07-30T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "idc" : "idc 1",
    "cic" : "cic 1"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a58dc3a1aadbcd8ae745758"),
    "fecIni" : ISODate("2017-07-29T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "idc" : "idc 1",
    "cic" : "cic 1"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a58dc671aadbcd8ae74575e"),
    "fecIni" : ISODate("2017-07-28T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "idc" : "idc 1",
    "cic" : "cic 2"
}
```

Grouping by idc, cic fields could be performed by query:

```js
db.cllAuditoria.aggregate([ 
    { 
        $match : { 
                fecIni: {
                    $gte: ISODate("2017-07-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                    $lte: ISODate("2017-07-31T05:00:00.000Z")
                }
        }
    },
    { $group : { _id : { "idc": "$idc", "cic" : "$cic"} } }
]);
```

Outcome will looks:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "idc" : "idc 1",
        "cic" : "cic 2"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "idc" : "idc 1",
        "cic" : "cic 1"
    }
}
```

If U want to count items in group:

```js
db.cllAuditoria.aggregate([ 
    { 
        $match : { 
                fecIni: {
                    $gte: ISODate("2017-07-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                    $lte: ISODate("2017-07-31T05:00:00.000Z")
                }
        }
    },
    { $group : { 
        _id : { "idc": "$idc", "cic" : "$cic"},
        count: { $sum: 1 } 
    } }
]);
```

Result:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "idc" : "idc 1",
        "cic" : "cic 2"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "idc" : "idc 1",
        "cic" : "cic 1"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

Hope, it will helps U. If your data differs, please, provide example of collection and what U want to get as a result.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por compartir tu experiencia, ahora mismo iré a la aplicación con tu solución.